# 404 ошибка при отправке post-запроса

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет.

Есть старый интернет-магазин,написанный еще на jQuery. На странице каталога при добавлении товара в корзину все отрабатывает отлично. На странице с найденными по поиску товарами в консоль падает ошибка 404.

Подскажите, куда смотреть, в чем может быть ошибка?

```js
function catalogProductNoVariations(event) {
   var prod = event.target;
   var prodId = $(prod).attr("data-goodsid");
   var pluid = $(prod).parents('.catalog_item').find('.popup-variations select option:selected').data('id');
   var data = {
      action: "addcart",
      id: prodId,
      flag: true,
      qty: 1,
      pluid: pluid,
   };

   $.post(location.href, data).done(function (msg) {
      var response = $.parseJSON(msg);
      $('.cart-prod-amount').html(response.count).css({
         display: 'block'
      });


      var tooltip = document.createElement("div");
      tooltip.append("Товар добавлен в корзину");
      tooltip.classList.add("hover-tooltip-success")

      setTimeout(function () {
         $(prod).parent().append(tooltip);
      }, 1000);
      setTimeout(function () {
         $('.hover-tooltip-success').remove();
      }, 3000);
   });
}
```

Comment: дебажить не пробовали? смотрите данные, которые приходят в метод добавления товара, есть вероятность, что из поиска они имеют другой формат

Comment: Да, все прям идентично. Причем на локальном сервере все работает, а на проде - нет :с

Comment: а на проде сверяли данные? может это только локально они одинаковые

Comment: попробуйте залогать все параметры в консоль

Comment: Пока я думаю, что проблема может быть связана с адресом, на который отправляется запрос. Но куда копать не понимаю.

Comment: так вот я и говорю куда копать, залогайте все параметры, которые приходят в пост-метод